Why is automorphism group a closed subgroup of isometry group?
A property about Kobayashi distance function $d_k$ is its decreasing property under holomorphic maps. That is, if $f: M \rightarrow N$ is a holomorphic map between two complex manifolds, then for any $p, q \in M$, it holds
$$d_{k}(f(p), f(q)) \leq d_{k}(p, q)$$
since any chain of holomorphic discs from $p$ to $q$ is mapped under $f$ to a chain of holomorphic discs from $f(p)$ to $f(q)$, thus has length no less than $d_{k}(f(p), f(q))$.
In particular, if $f \in {\rm Aut}(M)$ (i.e. $f:M\to M$ is a biholomorphism), then by applying the decreasing property to both $f$ and $f^{-1}$, we know that $f^{*} d_{k}=d_{k}$. Then ${\rm Aut}(M)\subset{\rm Iso}(M,d_k)$.
But why ${\rm Aut}(M)$ is closed?
Is the limit of a sequence of holomorphic maps holomorphic?

Are you assuming that your manifold is hyperbolic? What topology do you use on the group of isometrues?

@MoisheKohan $M$ is just a general complex manifold. ${\rm Iso}(M,d_k)$ has compact-open topology.

You should include this information in the question itself, as well as your attempts on proving this. As a hint: First solve this for domains in $\mathbb C^n$. But keep in mind that if $d_k$ is identically zero then every bijection of $M$ is an isometry. You probably want to restrict to continuous isometries.
